# Vector spaces and kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $\Bbb{F}$ and $T:V \to W$ a linear map. If $U \subset V$ is a subspaec we can consider the map $T$ for elements of $U$ and call this the restriction of $T$ to $U$, $T|_{U}: U \to W$ which is a map from $U$ to $W$. Show that

$$\ker T|_{U} = \ker T\cap U.$$

I know the definition of a linear map is

$f(x+y)=f(x) +f(y)$ and

$f(ax)=a\cdot f(x)$

I also know the kernel is the set of points which are mapped to zero.

However, I am struggling to piece this all together.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that by definition

$$\forall u\in U,\quad T_{|U}(u)=T(u)$$

Now if $u\in U$ such that $u\in  \ker T_{|U}$ then we have
$$T_{|U}(u)=T(u)=0$$
and this means that $u\in \ker T$ hence

$$\ker T_{|U}\subset U\cap \ker T$$
Conversely if $u\in U\cap \ker T$ then 
$$0=T(u)= T_{|U}(u)$$
hence $u\in \ker T_{|U}$ and we have the double inclusion. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a vector $v$ from $\ker T|_U$ and show that it lies both in $\ker T$ and in $U$. It is simple to do both, since $\ker T|_U$ is a subspace of $U$ and $0=T|_U(v)=T(v)$.

Then, show that if a vector $v$ lies both in $U$ and $\ker T$, it also lies in $\ker T|_U$. Again, a simple task, since $T_U(v)=T(v)$ for $v$ (because $v\in U$) and $T(v)=0$ (because $v\in\ker T$).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the kernel is the set of points mapped to zero, i.e.

$$\ker{T} = \{x \in V | T(x) = 0\}$$

Then $T$ is restricted to $U$, we need only consider points $x \in U$:

$$\ker{T|_U} = \{x \in U | T(x) = 0\}$$

Since $U \subset V$, this is the same as the points $x$ that are both in $\ker{T}$ and in $U$, in other terms:

$$ker{T|_U} = \ker{T} \cap U$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove the double inclusion: Let $T'$ the restriction, let $x \in ker T'$, obviously $x \in U$, by definition of Kernel of a linear operator defined over $U$. But by the fact that $U \subset V$ then if $u \in U \Rightarrow u \in V$ and $0=T'(u) = T(u)$

Answer (score -1):

We know that $kerT=\{v\in V| f(v)=0\}$

So that $kerT|_U=\{v\in U|f(v)=0\}$

So if $v\in ker T|_U$ then $v\in U$ and $v\in ker T$ which shows that $kerT|_U \subset ker T \cap U$

Now if we take $v\in ker T \cap U$ then $v\in U$ and $v\in ker T$ and so $v\in ket T|_U$ which gives $KerT\cap U\subset KerT|_U$

Hence we have shown that $ker T|_U=ker T \cap U$